# When you should implement a refresh token and how to remain stateless?

Tags: security, authentication, jwt, refresh-token, stateless

I'm implementing an authentication system.
The system currently runs with JWT, and without a refresh token.
To let the user stay logged in for a reasonable amount of time, we decided to set the expiration time for the token to 12 hours.
I saw that the recommended time for an expiration is 15 minutes.

**My first question** is, does every application that wants to let the user stay logged in for more than 15 minutes, needs to implement a refresh token?
And if so, is revoking is the only reason why, or the security manner (saving the refresh token in an httponly cookie and JWT in memory, instead of exposing the token in a cookie) is a reason as well?

When I looked for refresh token advantages, I mostly saw that people were talking about revoking, and taking the security manner as an implementation detail of the refresh token, and not as an advantage.
But for my understanding, it is also one of the advantages of the refresh token.

I didn’t find an expiration time standard for a JWT without a refresh token. I wonder if it’s because it’s too dangerous to not implement a refresh token in large systems, from a security perspective.

**My second question** is, is it possible to implement a refresh token and remain stateless, by adding the identity claims into the refresh token (so I could generate a new JWT without hitting the DB) and give up on revoking? Is it a security flaw?

In all of the Implementation examples I saw for a refresh token, I never saw one that is stateless, because they all wanted to enable revoking.

**My third question** is, if I’m not implementing an option for revoking the token, expect from the security advantage that I mentioned in question one, is there a reason to use refresh token and not just create a new JWT with a new expiration time, each time the system is getting a request?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your questions:

1. If you want the users to stay logged in longer, than implementing a refresh token is one of the approaches to take. I have seen people on Stack Overflow that did a token refresh based on the authentication token every 10 minutes or so, but I believe this approach is a bit more troublesome than a refresh token. I can also imagine to open a session on the auth server, put the session id in a cookie and refresh the JWT auth token based on the session. There is nothing wrong with doing it like this.
2. Yes. As tokens are signed, you can put information for future authorization also in the token. (Don't put in anything sensitive, as this will be information visible to anybody). Just think about how the system should behave when e.g. access rights of the user are changed. Is it ok for the user to run with his access rights around until he logs out? Assume you accidentally give the user admin rights. You would like to have them revoked with the next JWT auth token, wouldn't you?
3. So, you would like to have an auth token lasting as long as a refresh token? Noting would happen immediately. The world would still be turning and the sun would still be shining. We do this separation into auth and refresh tokens because we want to be able to deal better with crisis situations. An auth token is what you use everywhere all the time. If one of the services leaks the tokens to the public, you don't want to end up exposing all the data of your users in a matter of minutes. If the tokens become invalid after some minutes, then even if they leak, the attacker has a small time window to perform the attack.

Answer (score 1):

It only makes sense to use a refresh token, if you can protect it in a way that is different from the access token. If they are stored the same on the client, there is very little benefit (there is some, related to TLS vulnerabilities, but probably not so much that would support implementing a separate refresh token).

So this is the reason the refresh token is usually stored in a http only cookie, so that it's protected from XSS. The access token could also be best stored that way, but then you would not be able to send it to different origins.

Revocation is a different question. You cannot revoke truly stateless tokens, so if you need token revocation, you will have to implement a stateful solution. This can be with or without refresh tokens, from the statelessness perspective it doesn't matter which one you revoke.

So, while you should always consider your own threat model (what threats do you want to mitigate to what extent, and how), as a basic rule of thumb, you should

- Implement a plain old stateful session with only a session id sent to the client (not tokens of any kind) if you don't need statelessness (most applications actually don't need this), AND you always just send the token to its origin (you don't have single sign-on or similar where the token obtained from something like an identity provider or auth server is used on different services).
- Implement access tokens stored in httpOnly cookies if you really need to be truly stateless, but you don't have a separate identity/authentication server or single sign-on and you always just send the token to its origin.
- Implement short-lived access tokens stored by Javascript (eg. in localStorage) with longer-lived refresh tokens stored or a session id stored in a httpOnly cookie for the authentication/identity provider if you need single sign-on / federated identity, OR if you have multiple services that will consume your access token. In this case you can still consider longer-lived access tokens without a refresh token, but you will be running the risk of a compromised token with attackers having more time to actually use them. You can try to mitigate this with revocation, but the thing is, you likely won't notice in time, so I'd consider that a weak mitigation. And a medium complexity Javascript app will likely be vulnerable to XSS (regardless of the framework used, but some are more likely).

So how long an expiry time you would want to accept for your access tokens entirely depends on your exact use-case and your risk appetite - but it's important you make an informed decision.